# CGRect sprites issue in cocos2d-android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, cocos2d-android

In my cocos2d-android game project, random number of targets falls from top surface on to the ship, when both intersect ship should get deleted, i have done the coding but "ship" is not getting deleted. is that CGRect sprite will not get deleted? does anybody know this?

```
LinkedList<CCSprite> targetsToDelete = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();

for (CCSprite target : _targets)
{
    CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(target.getPosition().x - (target.getContentSize().width),
                                    target.getPosition().y - (target.getContentSize().height),
                                    target.getContentSize().width,
                                    target.getContentSize().height);



    CCSprite ship = CCSprite.sprite("ship150.png");
    ship.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(30,200));
    ship.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.ccp(0,0));
    ship.setTag(25);
    addChild(ship);
    //  ship.setVisible(false);


    CGRect shipRect = CGRect.make(ship.getPosition().x - (ship.getContentSize().width/2),
                                  ship.getPosition().y - (ship.getContentSize().height/2),
                                  ship.getContentSize().width,
                                  ship.getContentSize().height);
    System.out.println("ships to delete continue... : " + volume);
    if (CGRect.intersects(targetRect, shipRect))
    {

        System.out.println("ships intersected:)@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@... : " + volume);
        removeChildByTag(25, false);

    }

}
```

Comment: is your adding brand new `ship` for every target in _targets intended?

Comment: thanks for your reply, there is only one ship and many targets @Kreiri

Comment: is that something like parent.removeChild(node, true); has to be given? @Kreiri

Comment: I'm talking about lines `CCSprite ship = <etc etc> addChild(ship);`. For every target in _targets you create a "ship150.png" sprite and add it to layer (I assume your code is called in update loop of a layer). Is this intended? Did you really want such behaviour when you wrote this code?

Comment: yes my code is in update loop, since in update method _targets are used so placed this code in this, for every target in _targets i dont want to create a "ship" sprite, only one is enough. @Kreiri

Comment: are you by any chance setting the position of your parent node?

Comment: should i need to delete the parent node? i found like this, public void removeMe(CocosNode node) {
            parent.removeChild(node, true); is this correct? @ParvazBhaskar

Comment: no you don't have to remove the parent node, I asked just because if you have changed the position of your node then you'll have to add the offset of node from origin to the rectangle positions that you're giving.

Comment: i'm not able to get wat ur telling, please can u be more clearer? @ParvazBhaskar

Comment: is the log printed when the target intersects ship? Is your "If" condition for checking intersections is being met?

Comment: yes i'm able get the log message, ship is getting intersected, but not getting removed @ParvazBhaskar

Comment: hi Please provide feedback for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in update loop and this way you are adding ship to your loop every time.Its actually deleting you might not be seeing the effect. Take out the code that adds your ship out of your update code and put it in the initialization code,make the ship sprite global and then check for intersection.